# Which is the safest way to manage Rails database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

Since database.yml file contains some private information, we shouldn't put it under version control.

I just dig out a bunch of solutions for sync database.yml to my server, such as [this](http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/06/capistrano-and-database-yml/), I just want to know which is the safest way? Do I should only use `scp` to for that when I use Cap3 deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You should just create the database.yml on your server manually when you first deploy, and then use Capistrano's [linked_files](http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/) directive to persist the file across deployments. I think the default capistrano configuration contains an example of using the linked_files directive for your database.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the database.yml during deployment from your development machine to your server to shared/db if it doesn't already exist. After deploy and before assets are compiled copy the database.yml to current/config/database.yml.